# DefaultHttpClientが使えない

Tags: android

`Android Studio`で`DefaultHttpClient`を使おうとしても使うことができません。
現在のプロジェクトの`targetSdkVersion`は23で、`compileSdkVersion`も23です。
`minSdkVersion`は17です。

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

と打っても補完のインポートは出てきませんし、

`import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;`
とインポートしても`DefaultHttpClient`を使うことができません。
何をどう設定すれば`DefaultHttpClient`を使うことができるようになるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[公式サイト](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)に、 /app/build.properties に `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` を追加することで使用できるようになる、とあります。

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

[gradleプラグインがバージョン1.3.0(以降)でなければならない](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32190106/4506703)ようで、開発環境のアップデートも必要かもしれません。

なお、私の環境で試したところ、ビルドはできるようになりましたが、Android Studio上では依然としてエラー(クラスが検出できない)となっており、補完も効きませんでした。

今後もHttpClientを使用し続けるつもりであれば、[Apacheプロジェクト公式のもの](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)を参照するように変更した方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。gradleのバージョンが1.3.0以降で、useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'を追加してみてもエラーのままでした。なのでHttpClientを使わないやり方に変えたいと思います。ありがとうございました。